# why there is not serialVersionUID in de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Why there is no serialVersionUID in `de.hybris.platform.core.model.product.ProductModel`?

We face issue in deserializing the product model from `savedValueEntry`.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not mandatory.

> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects of the class, as described in the [Java(TM) Object Serialization Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html).

You should not have issue to deserialize it unless you change your compiler.

I don't actually understand you're issue with the `savedValueEntry`. Maybe there is a confusion with that, the objects are not serialized but the values they contains are encrypted and saved in the DB.

Comment: de.hybris.platform.hmc.model.SavedValueEntryModel

Comment: It stores newValue & oldValue (attribute value) as object stream.. If we have object as attribute  ... changing adding and removing the attribute in this object will cause issue while serializing of old data.

Answer (score 0):

A serialVersionUID represents a version of your class at a particular point in time. If you modify your class, your serialVersionUID should change. So when the JDK deserialize objects of the same class, it knows to which version of your class to deserialize it to.

But in case of hybris Item model classes, every time you will change the item type and/or its attributes, it will have a new serialVersionUID which would be different from the earlier version. Therefore, it does not makes any sense to specify a serialVersionUID to an Item model class which is designed to change frequently.

In short, the serialVersionUID is instrumental mainly at places where either transmission of object over network is required or the object needs to be de-serialized explicitly. Which is not the case of hybris Product Model.

Can you point me to the exact scenario when you are getting this issue which retrieving the savedEntry value(s)

Comment: de.hybris.platform.hmc.model.SavedValueEntryModel
It stores newValue & oldValue (attribute value) as object stream.. If we have object as attribute ... changing adding and removing the attribute in this object will cause issue while serializing of old data. –